# Joomla 3.8 404 error on incorrect links

Tags: php, joomla, http-status-code-404, joomla3.8

I have trouble with links in joomla 3.8. 
I have link like http://mysite.loc/my-category/my-subcategory/89 and this is correct link for material with id 89. 
But when i enter http://mysite.loc/my-category/my-subcategory/89asdasdasdasd 
Joomla show me this page, and repsonce 200/ok. How can i handle this and show 404 error for URL's like this ? SEF Is turned on

Answer (score 0):

Yes - this is how Joomla behaves. When you have something like `yoursite.com/my-category/123-blablabla`, Joomla will load the article having `123` as an ID. In fact, the article with ID `123` doesn't even have to be in the `my-category` category. This is one of the weird things in Joomla.

The solution to this problem is to remove the article ID from the URL as described [here](https://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-remove-the-article-id-from-sef-urls-in-joomla-3-7). Keep in mind 2 things though: 1) this is a core modification, and 2) the instructions on how to do so may be slightly different for 3.8.+.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution its works for me. 
In class ContentRouterRulesLegacy find method parse, and where its call query to db to execute the article info put.

```
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select($db->quoteName(array('alias', 'catid')))
                ->from($db->quoteName('#__content'))
                ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . (int) $id,'AND')
                ->where($db->quoteName('alias') . ' = ' . "'$alias'");

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $article = $db->loadObject();

            if ($article)
            {
                if ($article->alias == $alias)
                {
                    $vars['view'] = 'article';
                    $vars['catid'] = (int) $article->catid;
                    $vars['id'] = (int) $id;

                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');

                JError::raiseError(404, 'JGLOBAL_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND');

                exit(404);
            }
```